# Overriding classes in Java

Tags: java

Can I use ClassLoader's definePackage to override some packages from inside a jar?

For example, the application currently contains "javax.xml.bind" from abc.jar. If I call ClassLoader.definePackage(def.jar), in which the def.jar contains another version of javax.xml.bind, can I replace the classpath for the entire application to point to that of def.jar? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to put your jar ahead of the other one in the search order.  ClassLoader.definePackage does nothing that would be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you definitely can **not** use `ClassLoader.definePackage` to "override" some packages from inside a jar.

If I understand correctly, you want to make your JVM load any class under javax.xml.bind from def.jar while all other ones from abc.jar.  In this case you can (in my personal order of preference):

1)  Put def.jar before abc.jar in the CLASSPATH.  This requires that no class you want loaded from abc.jar is present in def.jar.

2)  Unzip def.jar, abc.jar, or both, and remove any conflicting classes so it is really irrelevant which jar comes first in the CLASSPATH.  Then re-zip them.  Or you can do this only on one jar and put it before the other.

3)  Use a configurable classloader (sorry, no public domain one that I know of; let me know if you find one).  This could be an interesting topic for an OS project, except that several initiatives with similar (but much broader) objectives are already ongoing, some at the core of the language.

4)  Create a classloader for this purpose, probably extending the default one.

Comment: OSGi can do sort of what you're talking about in #3, though it's pretty invasive to the application's structure.

Comment: @chrylis  You are absolutely right.  And there are at least 3 Open Source implementations.  But, as you say, it's too much of an overkill as to mention it as an alternative.

Comment: More overkill than rewriting the classloader? O:-)

Comment: @chrylis LOL Very good point. I could be biased by having some experience writing classloaders and none with OSGi.  I did put 3 (and thus OSGi) before 4, though :-) .

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs